# Java - Inheritance (Base & Child)

Tags: java

In Java file, suppose there are 2 classes - Class A & B, we can create a object of class A in Class B and can call methods of Class A. So then why we need to inherit Class A like "Class B extends A" as we can call class A methods by creating object of A in Class B ?

Comment: What this got to do with JavaScript and Selenium? don't tag spam.

Comment: You don't need to extends a class to use it in another class. Where have you seen/read it that you have to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Think about the real world: a Dog **is a** Mammal. It doesn't contain one! In such situations it can make more sense for Dog to extend Mammal.

One key use case is that the base class implements certain behaviors (methods) that a child class needs to have, too. Then inheritance is one possible solution.

But you are correct in the sense that composition is often preferred over inheritance.

Also note: Java is a statically compiled language. Therefore it is really important to express such relationships on a **type** level. In contrast to dynamic languages, Java has no concept of declaring (at runtime): this object here has a quack() method, so let's assume the object is of type Duck.